# Is the pointer to the PE-header at offset 0x3c in the PE-file always set to 0x80?

Tags: windows, assembly, portable-executable

> Is the pointer to the PE-header at offset 0x3c in the PE-file always set to 0x80?

I wonder why this pointer would change. I guess the DOS header and stub haven't changed, since they were first written.

The PE-header starts directly after these DOS artifacts, so is the PE-pointer always set to 0x80? If not, why?

Answer (score 10):

Many programs have a [Rich signature](http://www.ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm) which is appended after the DOS stub, pushing the NT header down by a variable amount.

It's also completely possible to use a different DOS stub, or none at all. It doesn't have to print "This program cannot be run in DOS mode", you could put a small DOS game there, a harddisk wiper, print something entirely different, whatever you want.

You can even, if you're careful, [overlap the NT header with the DOS header](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~ismael/Cursos/YC++/apostilas/win32_xcoff_pe/tyne-example/Tiny%20PE.htm), and thus use an offset < 0x40. This isn't even too hard, because the only parts of the DOS header that matter are e_lfanew and "MZ", everything else can be whatever necessary to make the NT header work. You'd just have to align e_lfanew with a part of the NT header that can safely have that value.

Comment: Thanks, none of my diagrams of PE show a Rich signature. Also, the DOS stub is not part of the PE standard ( I mean its content)?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen
I'm 100% sure you can put in DOS stub whatever you want (and it will be run correctly, as long as it is correct DOS executable). Some simple apps even used this to provide the multi platform executable, so it could be run both in DOS and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

no,  PE-header at offset 0x3c - this is IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.e_lfanew which can be any value >= 0x40